# How to differentiate a function $f:\mathbb{H}^2\to \mathbb R$ from the hyperbolic space along a horocyle?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider some function $f:\mathbb{H}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ and a curve $\gamma:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{H}^2$, $\gamma(t)=(t/c,1/c)=i/c+t/c$ where $\mathbb{H}^2$ is identified with the upper half plane $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_+$ with metric $\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}.$ I want to compute the second derivative of $f$ along the curve $\gamma.$ I tried to apply the chain rule but I am not sure how to compute the second derivative,

$$\frac{d}{dt} f\circ \gamma = \nabla_{\dot{\gamma(t)}}f = \frac{1}{c}\partial_{x} f(\gamma(t))$$
and
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f\circ \gamma = \frac{1}{c^2}\partial_{xx}^2 f(\gamma(t))+\frac{1}{c}\partial_x f(\gamma(t))\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}.$$

Any suggestions/remarks will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smooth structure on $\mathbb{H}^2$ is the one it inherits as an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$, and the coordinates $x$ and $y$ on $\mathbb{H}^2$ are **global**. This means you can forget about Riemannian geometry and treat this as a calculus problem, applying the chain rule twice to obtain $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} f(t/c,1/c) = \frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t/c,1/c),\quad\mbox{and}\quad \frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2}f(t/c,1/c) = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t/c,1/c).$$

You will probably not be immediately satisfied with this answer, as it is more instructive to understand how the general mechanism would work if one did not have standard global coordinates to work with.

Brace yourself for a very contrived way of doing it:

Whenever $M$ is a manifold equipped with an affine connection $\nabla$, and we have a curve $\gamma\colon I\to M$ together with a smooth function $f\colon M\to \Bbb R$, we have the relation $$\frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2} f(\gamma(t)) = ({\rm Hess}^\nabla f)_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t)) + {\rm d}f_{\gamma(t)}\left(\frac{{\rm D}\dot{\gamma}}{{\rm d}t}(t)\right),\tag{1}$$where $$({\rm Hess}^\nabla f)(X,Y) = X(Y(f)) - {\rm d}f(\nabla_XY)\tag{2}$$is the covariant Hessian of $f$ computed via $\nabla$, and ${\rm D}\dot{\gamma}/{\rm d}t$ is the covariant acceleration of $\gamma$.

To prove $(1)$, just write $$\frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2} f(\gamma(t)) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}(\gamma(t))\dot{x}^i(t)\dot{x}^j(t) + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}(\gamma(t)) \ddot{x}^k(t),\tag{3}$$then add and subtract the missing term with Christoffel symbols.

The only nonzero Christoffel symbols for $\mathbb{H}^2$ are $$\varGamma^x_{xy} = -\frac{1}{y},\quad\varGamma^y_{xx} = \frac{1}{y},\quad\mbox{and}\quad \varGamma^y_{yy} = -\frac{1}{y}.\tag{4}$$

So, as $\nabla_{\partial_x}{\partial_x} = (1/y)\partial_y$, we see that $\gamma(t) = (t/c,1/c)$ leads to $\dot{\gamma}(t) = (1/c)\partial_x|_{\gamma(t)}$, and therefore $$\frac{{\rm D}\dot{\gamma}}{{\rm d}t}(t) = (\nabla_{(1/c)\partial_x} ((1/c)\partial_x) \bigg|_{\gamma(t)} = \frac{1}{c^2} \nabla_{\partial_x}\partial_x\bigg|_{\gamma(t)} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{1}{1/c} \partial_y\bigg|_{\gamma(t)} = \frac{1}{c}\partial_y\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}.\tag{5}$$Similarly, we have that $$\begin{align} ({\rm Hess}^\nabla f)(\partial_x,\partial_x) &= \partial_x\partial_x f - {\rm d}f(\nabla_{\partial_x}\partial_x) = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} - {\rm d}f\left(\frac{1}{y}\partial_y\right) \\ &=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} - \frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}. \end{align}\tag{6}$$  Hence, by $(1)$, $(5)$, and $(6)$, we have that $$\begin{align}\frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2} f(\gamma(t)) &= ({\rm Hess}^\nabla f)_{\gamma(t)}\left(\frac{1}{c}\partial_x\bigg|_{\gamma(t)},\frac{1}{c}\partial_x\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}\right) + {\rm d}f_{\gamma(t)}\left(\frac{1}{c}\partial_y\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{c^2} ({\rm Hess}^\nabla f)_{\gamma(t)}\left(\partial_x\big|_{\gamma(t)},\partial_x\big|_{\gamma(t)}\right) + \frac{1}{c} {\rm d}f_{\gamma(t)}\left(\partial_y\big|_{\gamma(t)}\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{c^2}\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(\gamma(t)) - \frac{1}{1/c} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\gamma(t))\right) + \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\gamma(t)) \\ &= \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\gamma(t)).\end{align}\tag{7}$$